# Weird results using distinct() and count() methods on apparently similar code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql, postgresql-9.4

*The following strange behavior has been spotted with Rails 4 (Rails 4.2.2/ruby 2.2.1) and PostgreSQL 9 (PostgreSQL 9.4.4).*

Keeping in mind that grouping without aggregate expressions effectively calculates the set of distinct values in a column, the following apparently similar lines of code lead to strange and weird results:

---

Why does:

```
Item.select( :color, :size ).distinct.count  # ERROR
```

return an error, while instead:

```
Item.select( :color, :size ).distinct.count( :all )  # WRONG
Item.select( :color, :size ).distinct.count( :color, :size )  # WRONG
```

both return a wrong result (if there are duplicate records with the same values of `:color` and `:size`)?

---

And why does:

```
Item.select( :color, :size ).group( :color, :size ).count  # ERROR
```

return an error, while instead:

```
Item.select( :color, :size ).group( :color, :size ).count( :all ).count
```

correctly counts `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (color, size)) FROM items`?

---

Also:

```
Item.group( :color, :size )  # ERROR
```

return an error, as expected because *queries with a `GROUP BY` clause can only include in the `SELECT` list non-aggregated column references if they also appears in, or are functionally dependent upon, the `GROUP BY` clause*.

But instead Rails allows the following:

```
Item.group( :color, :size ).count.count
```

that also correctly counts `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (color, size)) FROM items`!

Comment: Are you really just asking why ActiveRecord blindly generates confusing and invalid SQL?

Comment: @muistooshort surely! why don't you fix it? ;-)